# Lighthttp FastCGI unable to start due to permission denied on Linux Mint 20

Tags: fastcgi, lighttpd

I get that in /var/log/lighttpd/error.log after start attempt:

> 2021-04-04 14:47:21: (server.c.1488) server started (lighttpd/1.4.55)
> 2021-04-04 14:47:21: (gw_backend.c.1404) invalid "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/cgi-bin" (check that file exists, is regular file, and is executable by lighttpd)
> 2021-04-04 14:47:21: (gw_backend.c.1452) --- gw spawning local \n\tproc: /usr/bin/cgi-bin \n\tport: 0 \n\tsocket /tmp/hello_fastcgi.sock \n\tmin-procs: 2 \n\tmax-procs: 2
> 2021-04-04 14:47:21: (gw_backend.c.1476) --- gw spawning \n\tport: 0 \n\tsocket /tmp/hello_fastcgi.sock \n\tcurrent: 0 / 2
> 2021-04-04 14:47:21: (gw_backend.c.451) new proc, socket: 0 /tmp/hello_fastcgi.sock-0
> 2021-04-04 14:47:21: (gw_backend.c.468) unlink /tmp/hello_fastcgi.sock-0 after connect failed: Connection refused
> 2021-04-04 14:47:21: (gw_backend.c.324) child exited: 13 unix:/tmp/hello_fastcgi.sock-0
> 2021-04-04 14:47:21: (gw_backend.c.599) gw-backend failed to start: /usr/bin/cgi-bin
> 2021-04-04 14:47:21: (gw_backend.c.601) If you're trying to run your app as a FastCGI backend, make sure you're using the FastCGI-enabled version.  If this is PHP on Gentoo, add 'fastcgi' to the USE flags.  If this is PHP, try removing the bytecode caches for now and try again.
> 2021-04-04 14:47:21: (gw_backend.c.1490) [ERROR]: spawning gw failed.
> 2021-04-04 14:47:21: (server.c.1496) Configuration of plugins failed. Going down.

Start attempt is

```
sudo lighttpd -D -f lighttpd.conf
```

followed by

> /usr/bin/cgi-bin: Permission denied

in terminal output. Previously, I tried

```
sudo chown -R lighttpd:lighttpd /usr/bin/cgi-bin/
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/cgi-bin/
```

with no affect on server start. My configuration lighttpd.conf is:

```
server.username             = "lighttpd"
server.groupname            = "lighttpd"
server.port                 = 80
server.modules += (
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_dirlisting",
    "mod_staticfile",
    "mod_fastcgi"  
)
fastcgi.debug = 1
fastcgi.server = (
  "/hello" => ((
    "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/cgi-bin",
    "socket" => "/tmp/hello_fastcgi.sock",
    "check-local" => "disable",
    "max-procs" => 2,
  ))
)
```

I am using script from here: [GitHub](https://github.com/jerryvig/lighttpd-fastcgi-c/blob/master/hello_fastcgi.c). How to run it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says

> invalid "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/cgi-bin" (check that file exists, **is regular file**, and is executable by lighttpd)

`bin-path` should be a regular file, not a directory. It should be the path to your application script. See for example [Lighttpd and FastCGI](https://turbogears.readthedocs.io/en/rtfd2.2.2/main/Deployment/lighttpd+fcgi.html).

Comment: Where do I have to place regular script file? Do I need to add extra privileges for some user? Thank you.

Comment: `"bin-path" => "/usr/bin/cgi-bin/hello_fastcgi"`, assuming that is the path to the hello_fastcgi executable.